# Why is form submission outputting same data multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

```
<form id="book-entry-form">
              <div class="form-group">

                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="book-id" id="book-id" readonly>
                <label for="book-name">Book Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="book-name" id="book-name" required="true">
                <label for="author-name">Author Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author-name" id="author-name" required="true">
                <label for="select-category">Select Category</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="cat-select" id="select-category">

                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit">Submit</button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Buttons.

```
<!-- button div for edit and delete and book issue -->
              <div class="btn-group-vertical col-xs-4" role="group" aria-label="">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newBookEntryFormModal"
                  id="EditButton">
                  <img src="./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/pencil.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                  Edit</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#OnDeleteModal"
                  id="DeleteButton">
                  <img src="./node_modules/bootstrap-icons/icons/trash.svg" alt="" srcset="">
                  Delete</button>
              </div>
```

The above is the form for book entry/update. Here's the jquery for the submission. I autofill the form fields with a selected table row.

```
$('#EditButton').on('click', function () {
                    $('#BookInfoModal').modal('hide');

                    //book entry form autofill 
                    $('#book-id').attr('type', 'text'); 
                    $('#book-id').val(rowEntries[0]);
                    $('#book-name').val(rowEntries[1]);
                    $('#author-name').val(rowEntries[2]);
                    $('#select-category').val(rowEntries[3]);

                    BookEntryUpdate($(this));    

                })



var BookEntryUpdate = function (obj) {

        if (obj.is('#EditButton')) {
            console.log("called by edit button");

            $('#book-entry-form').submit(function (event) {

                event.preventDefault();
                var formInfo = $(this).serializeArray();
                console.log(formInfo);

                return false;
            })
        }

.....

}
```

When I enter submit after clicking on any row on the table, it console logs once at first, but when selecting any other row and submitting, it console logs the same object multiple times. 
example:

For the first time.

`called by edit button
index.js:146 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

From second time onwards.

`2index.js:140 called by edit button
index.js:146 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
index.js:146 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
index.js:146 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

How to fix this? I want it to be printed only once.

Comment: Where is `#EditButton` in your `html` ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that part. Wait.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click the `#EditButton` you are adding a new event handler for `submit` on `#book-entry-form`. Since you only need one handler, just move that code outside `BookEntryUpdate`:

```
$('#EditButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#BookInfoModal').modal('hide');
    //book entry form autofill 
    $('#book-id').attr('type', 'text'); 
    $('#book-id').val(rowEntries[0]);
    $('#book-name').val(rowEntries[1]);
    $('#author-name').val(rowEntries[2]);
    $('#select-category').val(rowEntries[3]);
    BookEntryUpdate($(this));    
});

$('#book-entry-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var formInfo = $(this).serializeArray();
    console.log(formInfo);
    return false;
});

var BookEntryUpdate = function (obj) {
    if (obj.is('#EditButton')) {
        console.log("called by edit button");
        // ...
    }
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving my own answer here. Did something that fixed it. While the cause of it is what @Nick said, and his solution is one way of fixing it, the alternate workaround is unbinding all event handlers for submitting before proceeding with the current submission.

```
$('#book-entry-form').off('submit').on('submit', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var formInfo = $(this).serializeArray();
                console.log(formInfo);
                // ...
})
```

This fixed the issue for me. Hope it helps others.

Comment: Why remove it and add it back instead of just adding it once?

Comment: The event handlers are all messed up in the original files. First timer here. So, adding it once gets me back to the same binding problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Long term, you probably need to clean up that code.